# ipad camera and webview youtube video playing issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller

Rootviewcontroller has a webview that plays a youtube video
and it has one camera button.
 User can click on camera button and record video. 
**up to this point its working fine**

When I dismiss the camera controller and try to play the video in webview, its frame gets disturbed even though I tried removing and again adding on view.

When I dismiss the camera controller without recording the video its working ok...
Here is the image[image]
code to play video

```
 GDataEntryBase *entry2 = [[AppDelegate.feed entries] objectAtIndex:[tag intValue]];
    NSArray *contents = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup] mediaContents];
   NSString *urlString=[NSURL URLWithString:[[contents objectAtIndex:0] URLString]];

    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: black;\
    color: black;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\"><div>\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"736\" height=\"571\"></embed></div>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, webplay.frame.size .width, webplay.frame.size.height];
    NSLog(@"html=%@",html);
        [webplay loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Check its autoresize properties

Comment: i did check but it was layer problem i used hittest to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did check but it was layer problem I used hit test to solve this problem.

Here is a link that show how to use [hit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758388/uiview-hittest-problem)

Comment: Add more details to make this answer useful to others as well

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    [self viewDidLoad];
// or if u write code in your viewdidapper method than

    [self viewDidAppear:NO];

}
```

you can load your entire view again on cancel button click.

Comment: i did check but it was layer problem i used hittest to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Playing movies by using the webviewcontroller gives a lot of issues (for instance with rotation). It's always a better idea to use the dedicated movie classes.

If you still need to use the webview for some reason or the other, I found out that by:
- setting the RootViewController in a temp variable
- setting the RootViewController to nil
- restoring the RootViewController again with the contents of the stored variable

the whole viewstack is reinitialized and would solve a lot of the issues I had with the rotation going weird. Wo knows the 'hack' might work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the "`<div>`" tag?  Try removing them as see what happens.

Also, this link below worked for me and it provides good sample code.  I altered the way I was using YouTube to fit this model and was easily able to build a table populated by youtube links in the cells.  As you tapped on the cells, the video would play within a frame.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: i did check but it was layer problem i used hittest to solve this problem